# How to use multiple instances of a JFrame and access variables from another JFrame form

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am making a sudoku game, in which I have two separate JFrame forms i.e., Home.java and Avg_Game.java
I have made two instances of Avg_Game class in Avg_Game JFrame form.
One instance is used to get variable "Player" from Home.java Jframe and another is to generate sudoku within Avg_Game file.
Now the problem is if I just run the Avg_Game.java file then i it just generate sudoku and don't access the variable "Player" from another Jframe ....... and if I run Home.java file and open Avg_Game Jframe using a button on Home.java file then it is just access variable "Player" but not generates sudoku.But I want both should work...PLease help

/* in Avg_Game.java */

```
public class Avg_Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Avg_Game() {     
}

public  Avg_Game(String Om) { 
         pop = Om;
         initComponents();

}
String pop;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

int[] mat[];
int[] mat_sol[];
int n,sqn,k;

public Avg_Game(int n,int k) {
    this.n = n;
    this.k = k;

    Double sqnd = Math.sqrt(n);
    sqn = sqnd.intValue();
    mat = new int[n][n];
            initComponents();
    }
```

..........

..........

// in main

```
public static void main(){

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

            new Avg_Game(n,k).setVisible(true);
        }
    });      
}
```

/*in Home.java */

```
Avg_Game average = new Avg_Game(Player); 

average.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You  should have a "Model"-object that both frames use.

Comment: "in which I have two separate JFrame form"* - You should avoid that if possible, making use of modal dialogs or `CardLayout` instead. You basic question is really basic 101 Java, which you should have a grasp on before leaping into GUI based development. [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) would be one place to start

Comment: ok..Thank you . I just remove third constructor and it works